# Pass arguments to slot function built by QT Designer

Tags: python, c++, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I'm new to GUI designing and I started working with QT Designer 4.8.6. I'm connecting buttons to function using the signals-slots mechanism.

Here is some connections generated by the pyuic4 util to create the GUI script:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.btn_add_codes, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), MainWindow.sel_codes_file)
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.btn_add_xls, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), MainWindow.sel_excel_file)
```

The associated functions in my main python file (`path_codes` and `path_excel` are QLineEdit widgets):

```
class MainDialog(QtGui.QMainWindow, gui_v1.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def sel_codes_file(self):
        self.path_codes.setText(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName())

    def sel_excel_file(self):
        self.path_excel.setText(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName())
```

I want to use a generic function for all the buttons which actions is to search for a file and show the path in a LineEdit widget. I added this function to my MainDialog class:

```
def select_file(self, textbox):
        self.textbox.setText(QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName())
```

I modified the connection to:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.btn_add_codes, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), MainWindow.select_file(textbox=self.path_codes)
```

It's not working. The main window does not show with this code and I'm getting this error: `AttributeError: 'MainDialog' object has no attribute 'textbox'`

Is it possible to pass arguments to slots connection functions ? If so, what am I doing wrong ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Does this lambda work? At least that's how I do it with Qt when using C++.

```
self.btn_add_codes.clicked.connect(lambda codes=self.path_codes: MainWindow.select_file(codes))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. I'm getting the same error: 'MainDialog' object has no  attribute 'textbox'

Comment: ok that is because your MainDialog indeed has no textbox. It has nothing to do with the `connect` line. declare it in your class first: `self.textbox = QtGui.QLineEdit()` (or whatever type it's supposed to be ...)